# How do I prevent AppleScript from adding .0 to the end of a number?

Tags: applescript

When working with numbers, AppleScript always adds ".0" to the end of it.

How can I make it not do that?

I've tried using `(variable as integer)`, and it worked, but not for higher numbers as the integer byte limit is smaller than float byte limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured `text 1 thru -3 of variable` would work.